# autofac multiple registrations based on generics type

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have a class that recieves a generic type:

```
RequestHandler<T>
```

Now I want to register this class in Autofac multiple times based on the generic type.
Something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<RequestHandler<Request1>>().As<RequestHandler<T>>();
builder.RegisterType<RequestHandler<Request2>>().As<RequestHandler<T>>();
builder.RegisterType<RequestHandler<Request3>>().As<RequestHandler<T>>();
builder.RegisterType<RequestHandler<Request4>>().As<RequestHandler<T>>();
```

I know that the syntax is incorrect but I hope you get the idea.

so is this even possible? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RegisterGeneric` to map open generic types like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RequestHandler<>)).As(typeof(RequestHandler<>));
```